# If the Minecraft world is truly infinite, how can the sun and moon revolve around it?

Tags: video-games, minecraft

Minecraft is often portrayed as a truly infinite world where the only limitation is your creativity. But, we see day-night cycles as well as the sun and moon cycle ([this gif properly shows that](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Daylight_cycle?file=Day_Night.gif)).

How does this system work? Even the flat Earth theory can’t be applied to it as Minecraft world is infinite.

Comment: The ancient Babylonians thought the same. The sun goes behind a curtain at night

Comment: Not an in universe answer (which I assume is what you are after) but the sun and moon actually orbit round the player (not the world) and can pass through blocks, so they disappear through the ground a LONG way from the player. In multiplay each player will see there own sun and moon positioned relative to them.

Comment: It's a fantasy world. You can't expect everything to work by our rules and logic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not infinite. There's a theoretical maximum number of chunks

Comment: @Valorum in Bedrock it is. Though things stop working properly once you get far enough, it still keeps generating. Java edition used to be the same.

Comment: By suspending your disbelief

Comment: This is like asking about the invisible walls that keep you from leaving Skyrim. Trying to apply the games implementation details to the story can be fun, but is not likely to result in a clear answer, as the answers so far have shown.

Comment: If the Minecraft world is truly infinite, then sun must be infinitely far away and also infinitely large. (Assuming you want to ignore game programming)

Comment: Certainly qualifies for sci-fi but this question should be in arqade

Comment: @shanu This question is perfectly on topic here. It fits both so it doesn't have to be over on Arqade.

Answer (score -3):

It's not the same sun, there is simply an infinite string of suns travelling in one direction. When they are far enough away, it gets dark enough and looks sufficiently like the sun has gone down that it becomes "night".